# How do I run a sub query in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber], [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
WHERE reportColumn =  (SELECT DISTINCT(reportColumn)
                       FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
                       WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn 
                       LIKE '%someword%')
```

I get an error message saying

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or 
when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you read the error message because it tells you what happened. Does your query still make sense when the sub-query returns more than one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if subquery return more than one row then use `IN` rather than `=` as

```
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber], [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
WHERE reportColumn IN  (SELECT DISTINCT(reportColumn)
                       FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
                       WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn 
                       LIKE '%someword%')
```

OR

if u r sure that subquery return single row then use as

```
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber], [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
WHERE reportColumn =  (SELECT top(1) DISTINCT(reportColumn)
                       FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
                       WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn 
                       LIKE '%someword%' order by idnumber)
```

Comment: You should never use a top(1) without an order by, especially not in a situation like this. A top(1) without an order by potentially returns a different row each time it is executed.

Comment: Also, this error happens only when more than one row was actually encountered, so we can be sure that the subquery does NOT return only a single row.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do here. If we assume you want to return all reports records where the report column matches a distinct list of report column walues that all contain the same word, you are doing too much work. You can just write this:

```
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber], [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] 
WHERE reportColumn LIKE '%someword%';
```

If this is not what you want, please review your query, particularly column and table names. If you still can't figure out how to write your query in that case, post some example values and the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing `where field=subquery`, which is an equality test - the subquery MUSt return a **SINGLE** value, e.g 1 row with 1 value. now 2 rows, not 2 fields. If you're returning multiple rows, it must be `where field IN (subquery)`.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your subquery can only return a single record.  Try using `TOP 1` to do this.

```
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber],  [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE reportColumn =  (SELECT TOP 1 reportColumn
  FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn LIKE '%someword%')
```

Comment: You should never use a top(1) without an order by, especially not in a situation like this. A top(1) without an order by potentially returns a different row each time it is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Reason For Error : trying to compare the single value with multiple values.

Solution : either Restrict inner query to return 1 value or change the where condition to compare with multiple return set.

Compare with single value : 
SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber],  [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE reportColumn = (SELECT **TOP1** reportColumn
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn LIKE '%someword%')

OR

Comparing with multiple return set

SELECT [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[idnumber],  [SKULL].[dbo].[reports].[subid] 
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE reportColumn **in**  (SELECT DISTINCT(reportColumn)
FROM [SKULL].[dbo].[reports] WHERE [SKULL].[dbo].reports.reportColumn LIKE '%someword%')